# Angular homepage not loading on app launch when using observable - refresh and all is well

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, signalr, subscription

I have an Angular application which has an overview page as it's home page.  The overview data is fed from a SignalR feed which updates every second.

I moved the feed into a separate service which loads on application start.  There is an observable on the service which I subscribe the component to.  However when the application starts, it sees the observable as blank even though the SignalR connection is established and is receiving.  If I navigate around other pages and back, it never subscribes to the observable.

If I press F5 to force a refresh everything appears and I can use the application there after as intended.

Essentially this is what I have.  Thought I have tried the various ngInit methods and *ngIf on the html.  I have also tried a resolver via the angular router.  All give the same results of a blank screen until reloaded.  So I have to assume this is down to how I'm using the observable.  I've tried Subject, ReplaySubject but have been mostly using BehaviorSubject.  This concept seems to work elsewhere but not on the initial page when starting the application fresh.

Roughly the code is like this:

Service:

```
export class OverviewSignalRService {
  overviewSubject: BehaviorSubject<IOverview> = new BehaviorSubject<IOverview>(null);
  overview$ = this.overviewSubject.asObservable();
}

constructor() {

  this.startConnection("Overview");
  this.startOverviewListener ();
  this.startRequest();

}

startOverviewListener = () => {
    
    this.hubConnection.on("transferoverview",
      (data) => {
        this.overviewSubject.next(data)

      });
  };
```

Component

```
overview: IOverview;

constructor(private overviewService: OverviewSignalRService )
{
   this.overviewService.overview.subscribe(x => this.overview= x); 
}
```

I then have an *ngIf on the overview on the page.

```
<div *ngIf="overview">
```

Comment: Is the service provided in root?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
overview: IOverview;

constructor(private overviewService: OverviewSignalRService) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.overviewService.overview.subscribe(x => this.overview= x); 
}
```

You should not put code in a component constructor (except very simple assignments). You need to use Angular lifecycle methods e.g. `ngOnInit` `ngAfterViewInit`.

Think of `ngOnInit` as your constructor.

If not try `ngAfterViewInit` which fires slightly later when the view is ready.

PS: It's OK to put code in a service constructor because services do not have `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`.

Also make sure your service has this decorator `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`.

Comment: Already tried this, but tried again anyway.  Makes no difference.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Does your service have @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) ??

Comment: Also, worth adding some console.log statements to see when the code gets executed. Does the error handler on the subscribe ever get executed? Does the complete handler get executed? If the error handler gets executed then the subscription will never emit again (unless u handle the error) - likewise if it completes it wont emit again either